# How to structure a database for goods with various colors and sizes?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

What's the most efficient way how to structure a database for an eshop with products with various sizes and colors?

Say I have a product, a T-shirt. For example, what should be the table/column structure if I then needed to display how many red t-shirts in size XXL are left?

Hope you can understand my question.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables:

```
tshirts(tshirt_id, brand, size_id, color_id);
size(size_id, size_value)
color(color_id, color_name)
```

This is with assumption that the T-shirts will have only one color and not the mix of colors :).  If you want to associate more colors to a t-shirt, then you may have to introduce another table for one-to-many relationship between tshirt and color with a composite key.

```
tshirt_color(tshirt_id, color_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Three tables sounds good for this:

1. Products
2. Colors
3. Sizes

Each product row links to a color and size.  You can have products in as many or as few combinations of colors and sizes as you want.  The Products table could also have an inventory column that you could use to display how many are left.

Comment: Realistically, sizes will be fine as an enum field.

Comment: @SamDufel `enum` is the most evil column type ever created; I don't care about canards about it being faster